# How to access static class variable in static member function of same class?

Tags: c++

I provide my sample:

```
  class a
  {
      public:
           static int m_n;
           static  int memfuc();
  };
  int a::memfuc()
  {
        int k =m_n;
         return k;
  }
```

But the following sample throws linker error: unresolved external symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the implementation somewhere:

```
int a::m_n;
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't *defined* (as opposed to declared) your static class member variable.

You could put this code in an implementation file (.cpp) somewhere:

```
int a::m_n = 123456;
```

Comment: Did already ;) that always catches me... at least the compiler issues a helpful error message for that one!

Answer (score 0):

For a static, you have to define it as :

```
class a
{
    public:
       static int m_n;
       static  int memfuc();
};

int a::m_n = 0;

int main()
{
    a my_a;
}
```

my2c

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the member `m_n`, but you also need to access the member correctly.

You need to add:

```
int a::m_n = 0  // Or some number of your choice
```

Now m_n is *defined* you can access it anywhere, not just in other member functions:

```
int get_m_n()
{
    int k = a::m_n;
    return k;
}
```